# How to pass array to oracle stored procedure from java with ojdbc 12.1.0.2 driver?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, ojdbc

I was using `oracle 11` version and passing `java array` to `oracle stored procedure` like this

```
ArrayDescriptor Descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("COMMON_STRING128_LIST", oracleConnection);
String[] array = initializeArray();
ARRAY mer = new ARRAY(Descriptor, oracleConnection, array);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY);
```

than I updated my `oracle version` to oracle `12.1.0.2` and I am using `ojdbc7 12.1.0.2` and all this `classes` `(ArrayDescriptor , ARRAY )`  are deprecated now.

How can I do same think with `ojdbc 12.1.0.2`  driver and `oracle 12 database` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [oracle.sql.ARRAY javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ARRAY.html):

> Use java.sql.Array interface for declaration instead of using concrete class oracle.sql.ARRAY.

for example:

```
java.sql.Array array = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)connection).createOracleArray((...);
```